# Migrating to Google Maps V2. Neccessary to compile using Google Apis?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

Why it's neccesary to compile using “Google Apis” if the Google Maps V2 is included in Google Play Services?

i want to migrate my apps created with google maps v1 to google maps v2. I'm reading the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

The problem comes here, the documentations says that i need to add Google Play Services to my app, because google maps v2 is included there, so i did it. But in the next step, the documentation says that i must compile using Google Apis 13 instead of Android SDK 13.... so i dont understand it. If google maps v2 is included in google play services... why should i compile with Google APIS 13 (like when i used google maps v1) instead of Android SDK 13?

Comment: Where exactly did you read you have to use Google APIs 13?

Answer (score 0):

This whole confusion will go away if you realize that, android is opensource but google services are not.

So when you use google services like maps you must compile with google maps api so that, their classes are available to you while compiling.

Comment: you did not understand my question. If google maps is included in google play services lib, why i need to compile also with google apis?

Comment: theres something that i dont unsderstand, the documentation says that you must compile with google apis and i am trying to compile without google apis and i get compilation errors..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compile with Google APIs.

Comment: ¿? have you tryed it? if i dont compile with google apis i got compilation errors